# Sub works perfectly but calling from function does not work

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have a table in Excel as:

```
MOD  ACTIVITY PRICE
MOD1 0001  1.00
MOD1 0002  2.00
MOD1 0003  3.00
MOD2 0001  4.00
MOD2 0002  5.00
MOD2 0003  6.00
```

And I want to find out what is the sum of price where MOD is 'MOD2' and ACTIVITY is either '0001' or '0003'
Simply an equivalent to the following very simple SQL query:
select sum(price) as TotalPrice from TableName where modname = 'mod2' and activity in('0001','0003')

While reading different sources, I found two functions AutoFilter and Intersect and wrote the following Sub:

```
Dim rangeSum As Currency
Sub FindValue()
    rangeSum = 0
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="32-00505K"
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("0003", "0004"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Dim rangeFound As Excel.Range
    Set rangeFound = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells

    Dim rangeUsedForSum As Excel.Range
    Set rangeUsedForSum = Intersect(rangeFound, Range("E:E"))
    Set rangeFound = Nothing

    If Not rangeUsedForSum Is Nothing Then rangeSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rangeUsedForSum)

    'MsgBox ("Range: " & rangeUsedForSum.Address & vbCrLf & "Sum: " & rangeSum)
    Range("A1").AutoFilter
End Sub
```

If I run the Sub by itself, it works perfectly.
But if I call it from within a function:

```
Function GetValue(arg1 As String, arg2 As String) As Currency
    Call FindValue
    GetValue = rangeSum
End Function
```

And call this function from the Excel sheet, it returns 0 (Debugging shows no intersection) and my Excel gets filtered only by the second criterion and the filter is not turned off.

I am not sure if AutoFilter and Intersection are the best option as I believe there must be a simpler way to do this trivial thing but anyway, if the Sub works perfectly, then why it is not working through the function?

Comment: Any code called directly (or indirectly) from a worksheet cell cannot modify the sheet from which it's called (or pretty much anything else).  So, you can't Filter as part of your sub if it gets called from a user-defined function.

Answer (score 1):

Matter of opinion whether `a simpler way to do this trivial thing` but a formula may work, along these lines perhaps:

```
 =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"MOD2",B:B,"0001")+SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"MOD2",B:B,"0003")
```

or shorter version:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"MOD2",B:B,{"0001","0003"}))
```

Comment: Very small and very useful. Thank you. This does exactly what I needed. Anyway, still confused why not working when called from Excel sheet. And Tim Williams up there says calling from Excel should not modify or filter the sheet but mine does. I don't see how to attach my file here. Can I send it so one can check it? BTW, is there an eqivalent of SumIfs for text or Index/Match combination is my best bet?